# Select-UI not populating drop down

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-select

I'm trying to use AngularJS Select-UI but I'm having issues populating the drop-down. There are no errors that show on the console but the pull-down menu is not getting populated:

HTML portion

```
                            <ui-select ng-model="selectedUser" theme="bootstrap" on-select="onSelectCallback($item)">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a User">{{selectedUser.username}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in options.people">
                                <div ng-bind-html="item.username | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
```

Controller Portion:

```
function selectCtrl($scope, $http) {

$scope.options = {};
$scope.selectedUser = {};


var onUserComplete = function(response){
    $scope.options.people = response.data;
    console.log($scope.options.people);

}

$http.get("http://localhost/api/user")
    .then(onUserComplete);


$scope.onSelectCallback = function(item){
    $scope.selectedUser = item;
}

}
```

The data comes back as an array which I console logged out to look at:

```
Array(2)
0:{id: 1, username: "username1", $$hashKey: "object:130"}
1:{id: 2, username: "username2", $$hashKey: "object:131"}
length:2
__proto__:Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with simplified version?

e.g:

```
ng-bind="item.username"
```

Or even by defining `$scope.options = {};` directly (maybe the error is not in the then method.